# Access denied for user 'a9802737_mystor'@'10.1.1.31' (using 000webhost.com)

Tags: php, mysql, web, e-commerce

I'm creating an e-commerce website for our project following a series in youtube(link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaII5QhNCH0&index=2&list=PL5t0hrp1JCovPTJDC3lR3V5pKDG-xL5mI). It's a tutorial for an e-commerce website using PHP(IDE: Adobe Dreamweaver) and MySql.

As followed through the tutorial, I availed a free web hosting from 000webhost.com. Here(at 000webhost.com) I created a database with:

name ="a9802737_mystore"

host = "mysql9.000webhost.com"

username = "a9802737_mystore"

Then as indicated in the tutorial, I made a connect_to_mysql.php file.

```
<?php 

   //connect_to_mysql.php

   $db_host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
   $db_username = "a9802737_mystore";
   $db_pass = "*******";    
   $db_name = "a9802737_mystore";

   mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die("could not connect to mysql.");
   mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("no database");

?>
```

then create a table through code:

```
<?php 
   //create_admin_table.php

   require "connect_to_mysql.php";

   $sql_command = "CREATE TABLE admin(
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        last_log_date date NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        UNIQUE KEY username(username)
        )";

   if(mysql_query($sql_command)){
       echo"Your admin table has been created successfully!";
   }    else{

       echo"Critical Error: admin table has not been created";
   }


 ?>
```

now I'm getting an error:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user '    a9802737_mystor'@'10.1.1.31' (using password: YES) in /home/a9802737/public_html/storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php on line 10

[image: error]

How can I fix this guys?

A big thank you to everyone! :)

UPDATE: 
I used PDO instead of mysql_connect then I successfully connected.

But When I execute my create_admin_table.php is gives me this error:

[image: see this error]

Comment: first stop using `mysql_*` deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. also try once with empty password

Comment: if you correctly using correct  credintials for the database  then ask the support from 000webhost.com

Comment: Should you not be using localhost, assuming you're executing your script on said server? I would imagine for safety reasons, remote connections would be blocked.

Comment: @A-2-A I used PDO and I tried it using a mysql_quicktest.php file to test the connection and it returns success :)

Comment: @Valdoruous I made the host also localhost and it returned success. Problem is both hosts "mysql9.000webhost.com" and "localhost" returns success. Which should I use?

Comment: If you use PDO to start connection, you have to use PDO even in other mysql commands. You have to ask to your provider if you can use localhost instead of  ‘mysql9.000webhost.com’ (maybe you can find something in Customer Care pages)

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) you can find a basic PDO tutorial with information of how migrate from mysql_ to PDO

Comment: @fusion3k Trying it now. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I know that 000webhost blocks a lot of SQL stuff. :\ Also, for 000webhost apparently you should use their `mysql*.000webhost.com` as the host for your db.

Comment: @PXgamer Well, free stuffs will really render you limited I guess. Okay thank you I will use mysql9.000webhost.com as my host. :)

Comment: use localhost because someday you may move to a new hosting provider. mysql9.000webhost.com  will stop working

Comment: @Jeff apparently to my mistake, localhost was not working. It's just the mysql9.000webhost.com that's working so I will use that :)

Comment: @Jeff Yes, but 000webhost doesn't allow it ;) I guess he could just do a global class to include the db, then he just has to change it once.

Comment: @PXgamer Can you elaborate please? :) How can I make the host to "localhost" and use my website furthermore when my free trial with 000webhost runs out considering that I made the db using 000webhost in it's member's cpanel ?

Comment: Hi @Andre, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I just meant use a database. So, add it as an entry in one of the tables. Then, when the site is initialised, you can check that column and include the DB variable in your SQL queries. This would mean that you just have to update the db entry (to the host on your new site), and it would update all over your site.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you EVERYONE! I can now successfully connect to my database using PDO and "mysql9.000webhost" as my host and now can create a table through PDO also. Again thank you Stackoverflow!!

Comment: So how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

After  checking very carefully everything,  I found web was running great in my localhost, the problem here seems to be mysql remote access is blocked in free hosting , it looks we need to upgrade the plan to have access to the database completely.

Good luck everybody, almost no informacion on the net about this problem I saw many was facing.